# pandas: How to format timestamp axis labels nicely in df.plt()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
          prod_code      month  items      cost
0  040201060AAAIAI 2016-05-01      5    572.20 
1  040201060AAAKAK 2016-05-01    164  14805.19  
2  040201060AAALAL 2016-05-01  13465  14486.07
```

Doing `df.dtypes` shows that the `month` column is a `datetime64[ns]` type.

I am now trying to plot the cost per month for a particular product:

```
df[df.bnf_code=='040201060AAAIAI'][['month', 'cost']].plot()
plt.show()
```

This works, but the x-axis isn't a timestamp as I'd expect:

[image]

How can I format the x-axis labels nicely, with month and year labels?

Update: I also tried this, to get a bar chart, which does output timestamps on the x-axis, but in a very long unwieldy format:

```
df[df.bnf_code=='040201060AAAIAI'].plot.bar(x='month', y='cost', title='Spending on 040201060AAAIAI')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the dates as index, the x-axis should be labelled properly:

```
df[df.bnf_code=='040201060AAAIAI'][['month', 'cost']].set_index('month').plot()
```

I have simply added `set_index` to your code.